# jquery ajax failed request not triggering complete or error handler

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an ajax call like this:

```
var requestData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'js',
        url: "http://someServer", 
        success: function (data) {
            // do stuff with data
        },
        complete : function(data) {
            // try again in 5 seconds
            setTimeout(requestData, 5000);
        }
    });
};
```

All is well and good, and it works, EXCEPT: the server is a bit flaky, and from time to time, it fails to return a response. That's fine, but when that happens, the complete handler never fires. I've also tried using an error handler. Is there something else I can do? I've thought about using setInterval, but I'd really rather it do the next one after this one, not at a set time where they might pile up....

UPDATE: when the server fails, I get "Failed to load resource" in chrome's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that JSONP works by inserting a `script` tag into the DOM, rather than by XMLHTTPRequest.  `script` tags have no `onerror` property, so you can't test for success by conventional methods.  The only way to do it is via a timeout.

Something like this might work:

```
var requestComplete = {};
var requestData = function() {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    requestComplete[now] = false;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'js',
        url: "http://someServer", 
        success: function (data) {
            requestComplete[now] = true;
            // do stuff with data
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!requestComplete[now]) {
            setTimeout(requestData, 5000); // try again in 5 seconds
        }
    }, 5000); // give the JSONP request 5 seconds to work
};
```

Comment: ok. setInterval is working ok, so I guess I'll live with that. Thanks.